# Pattern puzzle help

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, pattern-recognition

I've spent hours on this puzzle, which shouldn't be too hard, and I'm sure I've got the right answer, but apparently it's wrong.  The problem statement:

> You are guessing a positive number X.  You may ask the
>   question, "Is X less than Y?" but the answer will be delayed by one
>   question (you won't receive the answer until the next question is
>   asked, note that the last question will not be answered).
>
> If you can ask 30 questions, how large can X be to guarantee that it is
>   determined every time?

So, I've covered several pages (after a few wrong turns) mapping questions, as follows (the "worst case" scenario for each):

> **X = 3:** Y < 2? Y < 3? {last question}? -> guesses: 3
>
> **X = 4:** <3? <4? <2? {}? -> 4
>
> **X = 5:** <4? < 2? <3? {}? -> 4
>
> **X = 6:** <4? <2? <5? <6? {}? -> 5
>
> **X = 7:** <4? <6? <2? <3? {}? -> 5
>
> **X = 8:** <5? <3? <7? <8? >6? {}? -> 6
>
> ...
>
> **X = 12:** <7? <10? <4? <5? <2? <3? {}? -> 7
>
> ...
>
> **X = 16:** <9? <13? <5? <7? <3? <4? <2? {}? -> 8

The pattern emerges where the number of guesses change at the midpoint between each power of 2:

> X = 2^2 -> 4 guesses
>
> X = 2^2 + (2^2) / 2 -> 5 guesses
>
> X = 2^3 -> 6 guesses
>
> X = 2^3 + (2^3) / 2-> 7 guesses
>
> X = 2^4 -> 8 guesses

Since 31 guesses is the limit, max 30 guesses (the solution) should be one less than that:

```
X = 2^15 + (2^15) / 2 - 1 = 49151
```

...but the puzzle page says "Wrong".  I've also tried the other powers of two and midpoints and numbers nearby, but no dice.

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?  I'm happy to do the legwork but I'm not sure where my mistake is!

Comment: You set up the problem with $X$ the number to be guessed, with $X$ contained in a set, $N$, about which set you say nothing. You ask how large $N$ can be, but the rest of the discussion seems to be about how large $X$ can be. I think you ought to edit your question for consistency of notation. I also suspect that if you are trying to guess a number between $1$ and $N$, then you should first ask if it's less-than-or-equal to $2N/3$ (roughly), then $4N/9$. The reason is that if the answer to the first question is no, then you've wasted the second question, but as compensation you know...

Comment: ...that $X$ is in the upper third. Keep guessing upper thirds this way. Maybe.